# 'Undefined control sequence \setkomavar'

Tags: macros, errors, koma-script

I ran into the error:

```
'Undefined control sequence
l.12 \setkomavar{subject}{Regarding: Code 123.456}'
```

My document preamble looks like this:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\signature{M.Y. Name}
\address{Street \\ Place \\ ZIP-code}


\begin{document}


\begin{letter}{Recipient \\ I know where your bed sleeps \\ I know where your house lives}


\setkomavar{subject}{Regarding: Code 123.456}


\opening{Dear Sir, Madam}


\end{letter}


\end{document}
```

What went wrong?

Comment: `\setkomavar` is defined for the KOMA-Script classes, such as `scrlettr`. It's not a common command for all LaTeX classes.

Comment: `\setkomavar` is only defined in the `scrlttr2` class. (`scrlettr` would be deprecated anyway).

Comment: You might find the `etoolbox` package of interest if you want commands generally equivalent to `\setkomavar`.  See especially '§ 3.1.1 Macro Definitions'.

Answer (score 5):

As `egreg` already mentioned in his comment the command `\setkomavar` is part of the letter class `scrlttr2` (thanks cgnieder) of the so called `Koma-Script` (see [here](http://www.komascript.de/komascriptbestandteile)). The most important `Koma-Script` classes are

- `scrartcl` (alternative to `article`)
- `scrreprt` (alternative to `report`)
- `scrbook`  (alternative to `book`)
- `scrlttr2` (alternative to `letter`)

In general the Koma commands are not defined in every documentclass. An example how to use the `letter` class can be found [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Letters) (Wikipedia).

Comment: This is not precise enough: `\setkomavar` is _not_ defined for all KOMA classes but _only_ for `scrlttr2`!